# swipe image gesture in xhtml for ePub

Tags: image, xhtml, swipe, epub

Im working on an e-book using calibre and dreamW. It contains lots of pictures so what i want to do is tap on one pic, make it pop at you (make it larger) and from that be able to swipe to the next image. I manage to make it happen in html, but not in xthml...
Any thoughts, ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Could you please a snippet of just as much as code as needed to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The swipe gesture you see in browsers are achieved by JavaScript, not by HTML. In some current EPUB implementations minimal JavaScript support is available (iBooks for example), but that would prevent your book being usable in other EBook readers. EPUB3 has better support of JavaScript and should make the books more interactive.

An alternative is to link the picture to an Appendix section, where you store one picture per page and the normal page turn will simulate the swipe gesture. There should be a link or a button in every page to take the reader back to the page from which he/she was re-directed.

Comment: Hi thanks. I should have been more specific when i said it was done in html. I did use JavaScript, and it worked in html. Tried to use that same code in xhtml but gave me some errors. Those errors are corrected now, but when the page shows in iBooks, shows one pic, then i try to swipe to the next and the page goes white. Thank you for your input. I will try to link the picture to an appendix section...

Comment: Perhaps a mater of semantics, but if iBooks can run jQuery (as it can, although I'm not saying it's a good idea), then it's hard to agree with a characterization of its JavaScript support as "minimal".